# Android Activity Recreated when orientation changes

Tags: android, screen-orientation

i am putting the following code in mymainfest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

but in android 4.0(ICS) the activity is recreated when i change the screen orientation.

just give me the generic code which will work for all android versions. because the above line is working for android 4.2 version

Comment: That should be working on Android 4.0. Have you overwritten any methods for catching orientation events?

Comment: no i am not overwriting any methods

Comment: Have you trying to use it through `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: NO iam not using it with fragments

Comment: try to give android:orientation="landscape" in manifest file. And also you should have default "layout" folder. Instead of layout-land.

Comment: then how the portrait mode will be enabled